# How can I create the effect of a view controller sliding partially after being pushed in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've seen quite a few apps doing this,  one in particular the facebook app when the more button on the top left is tapped.

I'm not sure what this is called exactly and my hunt for the answer has been unsuccessful.

Help appreciated

Kind regards

Comment: This is the default view transition effect in iOS7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to facebook style transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433660/how-to-facebook-style-transition)

Comment: google "iOS drawer menu"

Comment: @logixologist I'd like something compatible with UINavigation